# The page footer and the page sidebar override

Tags: bug, user-interface

See the screenshot, especially its lower right corner for a bug of rendering HTML (in the right lower corner of the Web page the page footer and page sidebar override). Got from https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/526343/edit

[image]

Comment: I get the same behavior with Chrome, IE and Firefox.